# Getting Data From Multiple Rows in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php

I have a university assignment where we have to create a dynamic gallery website using PHP and MySQL, and my idea is to create a portfolio for myself, however I have not done much PHP in the past and I am struggling a bit with getting this to work.

Basically, I want to get the 'thumbnail' row from each column in the table below and display them as separate images, however I can only seem to get the first column's image in the table to display, therefore if anyone knows how I can get multiple to display, that would be of great help.

http://i.gyazo.com/00dde8157ba75ecd81cc52ca59effa32.png

Here is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query($QuerySelect);

//-------------- STORE THE CONTENT WITH AN ID  = 1 IN A ARRAY --------------      -------------------

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

//---------------- DISPLAY RESULTS IN HTML -----------------------------------------------------


?>
<?php echo "<img src=\"" .$row["thumbnail"]."\"/>";?>
```

Note: there is code above this but it is just to connect to the database.

Comment: Can we have your SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query($QuerySelect);

//-------------- STORE THE CONTENT WITH AN ID  = 1 IN A ARRAY --------------      -------------------

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

//---------------- DISPLAY RESULTS IN HTML -----------------------------------------------------
?>
<!-- This part works exactly same as normal html -->

 <img src="<?=$row["thumbnail"]?>">
<!-- You can add <br> tag or else ... <?=$vvar?> is php shorthand echo method -->

<?


}
?>
```

But Seeing this comment:

```
//-------------- STORE THE CONTENT WITH AN ID  = 1 IN A ARRAY --------------      -------------------
```

I would say that dont get it by Id if you want to get multiple images. Get it any other way.

Like if you want to get images uploaded by try,

```
SELECT * FROM `imgtable` WHERE `uploadedby` = 'admin'
```

as sql query

**NOTE:** I strongly recommend that use `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_` as `mysql_` is depricated.

Comment: Thank you! This worked to display them, is there a way I can get them as separate images so I can style them individually?

Comment: you mean different image in different arrays

Comment: Sorry, extremely new to PHP;

Basically like in HTML, how you would display multiple images as separate IMG SRC's

Comment: np.. Be little more explanative.. like tell in bit other language if u r comforatble

Comment: can u tell ur sql query which is in `$QuerySelect`

Comment: $QuerySelect = "SELECT thumbnailid,thumbnail FROM homepage;";

Comment: isn't the current code doing the same.. if there are two rows, it prints them as 2 img... sry but can you post a small part of expected output ?

Comment: Ok, so this is what I currently have: http://gyazo.com/40d932a341ebb745fbdfaa696527bbde.png but the two images are in one line of code, therefore I cannot style it; as I would like to have space between them, and have them both link to different pages. e.g: http://i.gyazo.com/97702effa84a66ea4e19b6dac9c9d5ee.png

Comment: You want to split an image into two ?

Comment: Those are two separate images in the database, but they're displayed as one line of code (echo "<img src=\"" .$row["thumbnail"]."\"/>";) is displaying both of them. http://i.gyazo.com/982dd639f74646aed86e63fac76d21ba.png

Comment: I don't see any changes

Comment: ah ok, there we are - That img src tag is displaying both of the images, not just one (it's displaying the whole thumbnail column)

Comment: just add <br> after or before the comment.. that works exactly as HTML code..and you can do that much HTML

Comment: Ok, thank you - I've managed to get that to work now, but how would I add links to each individual image?

Comment: that part outside <? ?> works exactly as html... change it to:  `<a href="<?=$row['link']?>"><img src="<?=$row["thumbnail"]?>"></a>` (**Note** it works if you have a `link` column